# Вопрос по вёрстке в Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-xml, android-ui

Имею следующий layout для item-а в recyclerview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_hotel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_hotel_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_hotel"
            tools:text="Belleclaire Hotel" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/include"
            layout="@layout/include_stars_set"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_hotel_name"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_hotel_name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_hotel_address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/include"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include"
            tools:text="250 West 77th Street, Manhattan" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_distance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_hotel_address"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_hotel_address"
            tools:text="100.0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_suites_available_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/label_suites_availability"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_distance"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_distance" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_suites_available"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_suites_available_label"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_suites_available_label" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_hotel_image"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_hotel"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/iv_hotel" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при загрузке изображения через Glide в iv_hotel, происходит следующее после сборки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не совсем понимаю, как избежать данной ситуации ((
Может быть, кто-то может подсказать способ решить эту проблему?

Comment: Попробуйте `app:srcCompat` заменить на `android:src`

Comment: Не помогло(
Мне кажется, тут ошибка именно в подходе к вёрстке, только вот где, я не могу понять (

Comment: Тогда задайте конкретную высоту для ImageView. Например 100dp

Comment: Видимо пока картинка не загружена нет и ее размера, в разметке размер указан динамический - по размеру картинки, а привязка прогресса у вас к ее размерам, отсюда и смещение. Можно попробовать верх прогресса привязать к верху парента, а не картинки, но артефакты все равно будут, так как до загрузки картинки ее размер не известен. Можно решить, выделив для картинки фиксированную область, например 25% от экрана, ConstraintLayout позволяет указать размер в процентах. Указывать размер хардкорно в dp не стоит, так как на экранах с разной плотностью пикселей он будет разный на экране